# Integrate new permission in android marshmallow

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow

As we all know some changes have been made in api level 23(Android Marshmallow) in which we have to request for some permissions at run time that is on dangerous level like camera,read/write external storage etc. Is there any way to get Granular permissions from AndroidManifest file?

Comment: what is Granular permission?

Comment: permissions which is on dangerous level that i mentioned in Q.

Comment: You need to handle all permissions by yourself. You need to consider all possibilities and code according to that.

Comment: Try this it may be work http://stackoverflow.com/a/41221852/5488468

Answer (score 1):

Android Marshmallow introduces an entirely new spin on application permissions,Users now have the ability to revoke runtime permissions whenever they desire. This means that you can’t assume the app has access to the permission, even if it had been granted previously. You can refer this [lib](http://hotchemi.github.io/PermissionsDispatcher/) or this [guide](https://medium.com/ribot-labs/exploring-the-new-android-permissions-model-ba1d5d6c0610#.1jpsx34a6).I Hope this will help you out.

Answer (score 0):

1) You can get all the permissions given in your app using android api functions.

2) Then you can make a constant HashMap of dangerous permissions (which you are calling granular i guess).

3) When you will get all the permissions of your app just compare each permission individually either is it present in Dangerous Permissions HashMap or not.

Happy Coding :)

Answer (score -1):

Requesting permission is quite monotonous. One have to check permission each and every time whenever you use. For simplicity you can use [PermissionAcceptor-master](https://github.com/hp-harsh/PermissionAcceptor-master) library.

Almost all permission is included in this library.

You have to add few lines of code using PermissionAcceptor-master library like

```
new PermissionRequest(MainActivity.this,
        Permission.PERMISSION_CAMERA,
        PermissionCode.CODE_PERMISSION_CAMERA,
        R.string.permission_camera_rationale,
        R.string.permission_camera_denied,
        R.string.permission_enable_message, this)
        .checkPermission();
```

For more information, visit [PermissionAcceptor-master](https://github.com/hp-harsh/PermissionAcceptor-master).